# How to Convert Server Time To Current Time In Android?

Tags: android

```
try {
                    System.out.println("check response" + response);
                    JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONObject jobojectsecond = jsonobject.getJSONObject("Data");
                    mcdetail = new MsgComments();
                    mcdetail.setId(jobojectsecond.getString("Id"));
                    mcdetail.setUsername(jobojectsecond.getString("UserName"));
                    mcdetail.setUserid(jobojectsecond.getString("UserId"));
                    mcdetail.setCommenttext(jobojectsecond.getString("CommentText"));
                    Comment = jobojectsecond.getString("CommentTime");


                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssa", Locale.US);
                    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern");
                    sdf.setTimeZone(timeZone);
                    String gmtStrDate = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                    System.out.println("GMT 1" + gmtStrDate);


                    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssa");
                    TimeZone timeZone1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30");
                    sdf1.setTimeZone(timeZone1);
                    Date gmtDate = sdf.parse(sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
                    String str21 = sdf1.format(gmtDate);
                    System.out.println("GMT 2" + str21);
```

I am Using This Code For Convert Date Format In Android And We are receive date from server this code convert for calendar i want to convert .

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeZone fromTimezone =TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern");
TimeZone toTimezone=TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");

long fromOffset = fromTimezone.getOffset(calendar.getTimeInMillis());//Server date
long toOffset = toTimezone.getOffset(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

long convertedTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - (fromOffset - toOffset);
convertDate(convertedTime,"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

//Support function
public static String convertDate(String dateInMilliseconds,String dateFormat) {
    return DateFormat.format(dateFormat, Long.parseLong(dateInMilliseconds)).toString();
}
```